# Extracting multiple sub ranges into a contiguous dynamic array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to extract a number of blocks of data into one continuous dynamic array.

I can identify the beginning and end of the blocks with reference to their contents. There is some specific text in columns I can detect.

I also generate a dynamic array which lists the blocks.

There are a variable number.

I can do everything I need by adding a "take me" helper column which I can also generate by context.

However, mainly for curiosity etc, I was trying to do this from the list of blocks by generating a true/false array from the block list but couldn't figure out a way to do this (this would let me simply filter the data).

Comment: So what is the data you have, because the image contains a lot of different groups of data, but it's unclear if they're there from the start, or a result of your attempts (the attempts that you didn't include in the question to help us help you). Would this work, for instance?: `=LET(f,FILTER(B1:B22,C1:C22),HSTACK(IF(f="","",f),FILTER(I1:I32,J1:J32=TRUE)))`

Comment: B4:B22 is the source data, M7:N15 is the required output.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Sorry, my comment was intende for P b who had requested a clarification. Yes, it's good thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
=LET(x,B4:B22,FILTER(HSTACK(ROW(x),x&""),MAP(x,LAMBDA(s,AND(@TOCOL(s:B22,1)<>{"End","Begin"})))))
```

Comment: That's great. Took me a bit of deconstructing but avoids scan (which I have found sometimes doesn't recalculate on mobile)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it using `MS365` dynamic array formulas:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _seq, SCAN(0,B4:B22,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     _data, HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B4:B22),,4),IF((B4:B22="")*(_seq<>"End"),"",_seq)),
     FILTER(_data,(TAKE(_data,,-1)<>"Begin")*(TAKE(_data,,-1)<>"End")))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function to define variables which may be repeated and also makes easier to read.
- Using `SCAN()` function create an array of values to fill up the blanks from above.
- Using `IF()` function to do a condition check whether `B4:B22` is equal to blank and `_seq` is not equal to `End` if `TRUE` return empty else `_seq`.
- Combined the two arrays using `HSTACK()`
- Using `FILTER()` function to exclude those which are `Begin` & `End` to get desired output.

---

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(a,B4:B22,
     b,FILTER(HSTACK(ROW(a),a),
            SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(x,IF(y="end",0,x+1),IF(y="begin",1,0))))>1),
IF(b="","",b))
```

This uses scan to create a counter from `begin` (1) to `end` (0) if the previous value is larger than 0 than it adds 1 until it finds `end` so it resets to 0 until it finds the next `begin`.

The values of the array greater than 1 (to exclude the `begin` row itself is used to filter the (HSTACKed) row and value.

Finally to prevent blanks from being returned as `0` we add an IF to the filtered array `b` `IF(b="","",b)`